# View / See / Read cookies in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Until recently I could see and delete specific cookies
in Google Chrome this way:

```
chrome://settings/cookies
```

But now it's not working.  How can I see them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Now it's not working. Now can I see them?

> chrome://settings/cookies

This was changed in Chrome version (59.0.3071.115) to:

> chrome://settings/content/cookies

From Chrome version 73, it is:

> chrome://settings/siteData

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's not that comfortable as it was before though

Comment: @EddyUnruh just find out what it is for the current chrome version and make a bookmark called eg 'view cookies'. I just posted an answer for the current, `chrome://settings/siteData` goes direct to a page with the list

Answer (score 3):

as of Chrome 73,  `chrome://settings/siteData`

Answer (score 0):

Try [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo?hl=en&authuser=0) chrome extension.

You can edit a cookie using a form by clicking the cookie row in the table.
[image]

You can also select multiple cookies and edit via JSON Editor.

[image]

Delete multiple cookies.
[image]

Full list of features can be found [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo?hl=en&authuser=0):

Answer (score -1):

You can try using an extension like this one: [EditThisCookie](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg)

Comment: @DonaldDuck it's not link only. It has words before it.  And there isn't much more information he can provide if the person that wrote the extension pulls it then they pull it.  The URL to a chrome extension directly identifies the extension by ID.  That's typically the official link or as close as you'll get to the official link.

Comment: @DonaldDuck   It's written by Francesco Capano. But that isn't that relevant. There is  www(dot)editthiscookie(dot)com But it has some legit stuff and some junk links that one wouldn't want, and not much useful. The link to use is exactly the one that "Seer" gave. His answer is fine and gives a description too.

Comment: @barlop [This FAQ answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/513819) says how to recommend software, and this answer doesn't really follow those guidelines (points 5 and 6 are missing, that is it doesn't say how to use the extension or how the extension answers the question).

Comment: @DonaldDuck Well whatever the FAQ says, you should use some common sense.  The usage of the thing is you click the symbol for the extension (which is pretty much all you ever do with an extension),  and you see a list of cookies.  It's not like trying to explain to somebody how to use nircmd. When a program is that simple, it's more than intuitive enough. Anybody that has ever used a single chrome extension could not fail. Even as google chrome extensions go it's extremely simple.

Comment: @DonaldDuck If a user asked for how to view a box with the word "BANANAS" written in it. And somebody linked to such a program that did just that. Nothing more, nothing less. Then it's intuitive enough. Your run the program and can't go wrong. So, common sense(or insight) is called for, rather than just blindly reading rules.

Comment: The main issue is here Chrome is fine for viewing, and it looks like EditThisCookie gives wrong information and is malware/adware or at best, borderline adware  
 https://superuser.com/questions/1430151/why-does-chromes-editthiscookie-extension-seem-to-list-some-cookies-as-sess/1430211#1430211   And by the way that link includes some pictures from that extension